# IAM policy to allow S3 access to specific IAM role in the same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a AWS account which have some IAM user having access to s3 buckets. I also have a S3 bucket that contains sensitive information. Is there a policy where I can deny the access to all users except the particular role and group ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is a bucket policy that regulates access to that specific bucket. The following AWS security blog article describes exactly how this can be done:

[How to Restrict Amazon S3 Bucket Access to a Specific IAM Role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/)